# Only open magnificPopup if parent of target has specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, magnific-popup

I have the following popup initialization:

```
$('.notcheckedin .checkinbtn').magnificPopup({
  type: 'inline',
  preloader: false,
  focus: '#checkin-code',
  callbacks: {
    ...etc...
  }
}
<div class="exhibitor notcheckedin">
  <div class="checkinbtn"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

The popup bit works fine. However, when I dynamically removeClass('notcheckedin') from the parent div, it still opens the popup. I only want it to open the popup if the target's parent class hasClass('.notcheckedin').

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I'm using a single div as the source of my popup, so it was pretty easy once I looked at open() and the items option. The following worked for me:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.notcheckedin .checkedinbtn', function(e) {
  var target = $(this);
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: '#checkin-code-popup',
      type: 'inline'
    },
    preloader: false,
    callbacks: {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

It opens the popup when .checkedinbtn is clicked, but *only* when it's parent is .notcheckedin.